# MUI Waterfall toolbar implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I'm using something very similar to this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/1op5mqq9oq

Click on the checkbox's and the `<Toolbar />` appears, when you scroll down the page the `<Toolbar />` stays put at the top and go out of sight. I was under the assumption that it can be a "waterfall" toolbar that comes out of the box, I could be wrong but assumed it would be a class or prop that could be applied. Here is the demo code:

I ultimately want the toolbar to stay at the top of browser on scroll and then fix itself back into position when return to the top.

```
<Toolbar
      className={classNames(classes.root, {
        [classes.highlight]: numSelected > 0,
      })}
    >
      <div className={classes.title}>
        {numSelected > 0 ? (
          <Typography color="inherit" variant="subtitle1">
            {numSelected} selected
          </Typography>
        ) : (
          <Typography variant="h6" id="tableTitle">
            Nutrition
          </Typography>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className={classes.spacer} />
      <div className={classes.actions}>
        {numSelected > 0 ? (
          <Tooltip title="Delete">
            <IconButton aria-label="Delete">
              <DeleteIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        ) : (
          <Tooltip title="Filter list">
            <IconButton aria-label="Filter list">
              <FilterListIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        )}
      </div>
    </Toolbar>
```

There is a link to waterfall toolbar on material Design - https://material.io/develop/web/components/toolbar/ Seems like this is a complete different implementation that I don't want to do.

Has anybody implemented this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the CSS [`position: sticky`](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/) is what you might be looking for